# load .dll ressource as string

Tags: c#, dll

I've got a function which needs to get path to a dll file for running them.
To make use of my app easier I don't want to let the user type in path for dll file. I added dll file as ressource already but my methode needs to get the path to the .dll file as string. How to get the string of my dll file called "test2.dll"?
All I found was about the use of functions from .dll files in the program itself, but not loading the path to this included .dll.

Comment: The path would be relative from where the executable is running. If you can get your applications path and you know where the resource should be located relative to your apps path then it is as easy as concatenating strings. Also look at Path.Combine()

Answer (score 0):

```
string assemblyFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

you can try with this

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

will give you the patch of executing assembly then:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

[here is more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx)

Comment: But how to load the assembly? (called test2.dll in my project)

Comment: My .dll (dlltest.dll) is added as a ressource and is built into the application, hope you understand what I mean: [picture](http://puu.sh/dxbot/d4d05c8006.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you, it sounds like you have a DLL file that is an embedded resource in your project and you want to be able to extract that DLL and then load the resources from that DLL. Here is an example.

First, you need to extract the DLL to a byte array:

```
byte[] buffer;
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("SomeNamespace.somefile.dll"))
{
    buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

So now you have this DLL file contained into your `buffer` byte array. Next we need to write the byte array out to a file somewhere:

```
string file = Path.GetTempPath() + "\\somefile.dll";
File.WriteAllBytes(file, buffer);
```

Now, finally, you can read in your DLL and extract whatever resource you need to:

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load(file);
using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("SomeNamespace.someresourcefile.png"))
{
    // Read in stream and do something with the resource
}
```